# Utilisation du pronom « en » dans ma phrase

Tags: pronoms

Je voulais dire en français : *My uncle was a huge fan of Mauriat and his orchestra. He used to have a large stack of CDs of his music.*

Mon oncle était un grand fan de Mauriat et son orchestre. Il **en** avait un grand tas de ses CDs audios.

Mes questions ici : 
1. Est-ce que la phrase est correcte grammaticalement​ ?
2. Comment utiliser le pronom *en* ici ?  Est-ce que je l'ai utilisé correctement ?

Comment: Plutôt qu'*un tas de CDs*, j'utiliserai *de nombreux CDs*

Comment: Le mot **CD** est invariable en Français et ne prend donc jamais de **s**

Comment: "Il avait un tas de CD devient "il en avait un tas". En remplace le mot CD. J'ai un tas de robes dans mon armoire. J'en ai un tas. Un tas est un mot marqué comme familier et parlé.

Comment: L'expression "J'en ai un tas" seule est familière, mais "il y avait un tas de CD" ne l'est pas

Comment: Au delà de la validité de la phrase: un simple _Il avait un gros tas de ses CD audios_ sonne bien mieux; Il n'est pas nécessaire d'utiliser le _en_ puisque le _ses_ note déjà la référence vers Mauriat. De plus, mais c'est juste un ressenti, je trouve _un gros tas de_ plus facile à utiliser que _un grand tas_.

Answer (score 1):

1. with a comma after *tas*, it is acceptable but a poor translation:

> *Il en avait un grand tas, de ses CDs audios.*

2. If you want to use *en*, you might write:

> *Mon oncle était un grand fan de Mauriat et son orchestre. De ses CD audio, il en avait plein.*

or, spoken style:

> *Des CD de lui, il en avait plein / il en avait un paquet.*

Breaking the sentence that way is not really necessary, you might have written:

> *Mon oncle était un grand fan de Mauriat et son orchestre. Il avait une grosse pile de CD audio de lui.*

Note that acronyms stay invariable in French: *des CD*, not *des CDs*.

Comment: Vous m'avez appris plus d'une chose avec votre réponse. Merci beaucoup.

Comment: Question - in your answer, you say de CD and des CD - which is correct?

Comment: Pourquoi pas dire que "en avait un tas de CD" est une erreur puisque si tu as un tas de quelque, t'en as un tas? Je ne vois pas cela nulle part dans ta réponse. Cad, que la même proposition ne pas avoir le **en** et les trucs. Il faut au moins deux propositions. En remplace les CD.

Comment: @Lambie J'ai écris que c'était acceptable s'il y avait une virgule, ce qui sous entend que ça ne l'est pas sans. D'autant plus qu'en français parlé relâché, la pause n'est pas toujours forcément marquée.

Comment: @jlliagre Oui, tu as donné des exemples de phrase qui le montre  mais tu n'a pas dit que le **en** peut remplacer un objet. Souvent, il y a deux personnes qui se parlent, et seulement la deuxième va reprendre anaphoriquement le(s) objet(s) en utilisant le en. Jeanne: Tu aimes les livres, toi? Marie: Oui, je les aime et j'en ai des tas. Ce genre de chose, p.ex. Il me semble utile de le dire pour ceux qui cherchent à parler comme on parle vraiment.

Comment: @kjstinson Everything is correct in my reply :-) **De** and **des** are different beasts!